# Does ROS can help me with sending the kinect data from Turtlebot to a server

Tags: ros, turtlebot2, turtlebot, face-recognition, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I just got Turtlebot 2 robot, and I’m gonna start working on a face recognition project. The scenario will be something like this: the robot navigates in indoor environment and sends the Kinect data to a server. The server does face recognition, and sends the result to the robot. I'm really new with this stuff, so I'd like to have some ideas of where to start with all this.
My question is this, how would ROS help me? What are the best tools and libraries to implement this kind of project?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54854/does-ros-can-help-me-with-sending-the-kinect-data-from-turtlebot-to-a-server/) by [TheSkyfall](https://answers.ros.org/users/4174/theskyfall/) on ROS Answers with karma: 39 on 2013-02-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I haven't used Turtlebot, but I use the Robotino which is similiar, and the scenario you mentioned can be be implemented using ROS. I have the robotino connected to my laptop via WIFI and it sends the sensor data to my laptop (ubuntu 12.04, ROS fuerte). I have the Kinect connected to my laptop and I do some processing and then send commands to the robotino for navigation. So my whole system is integrated by ROS and communicates via the ros servers.

As for what libraries you should us, I am sure opencv will be useful for face recognition and of course the cvbridge which you will use to convert ROS type images to opencv type images and vice versa. If you require any depth/range data for 3D reconstruction, look at the Point cloud library.

But before all that, I recommend going through the [ROS tutorials]((http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials) first in which you will learn the basics of the ROS communication systems and tools.

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) with karma: 735 on 2013-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TheSkyfall](https://answers.ros.org/users/4174/theskyfall/) on 2013-02-13**:
Thank you Yousif. Since you have worked on something similar, could you please tell me what did you use to send data from the robot to the laptop and vise versa? I mean does ROS provide any library for that?

**Comment by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) on 2013-02-13**:
I am using Robotino, which is supported by ros and already has ros-wrappers. I did not need to do much, everything has been already provided. The robotino has a wireless router built in and I connect to it and launch the robotino_node.launch.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can communicate between your turtlebot and server by creating a network between them.

Go through this tutorial

[http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/TurtleBot/Network%20Setup>](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/TurtleBot/Network%20Setup%3E)

---

Originally posted by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) with karma: 1610 on 2013-02-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1